# working hours for bussiness

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object invoice in which i have three custom fields `Work_Start_Time__c`, `Estimate_Time_To_Complete__c`, and `Target_Date_Time__c`. We have 9 hours working hours in a day from 9 am to 7 pm.

If a user enters today's date in `Work_Start_Time__c` and time is 3 pm and in `Estimate_Time_To_Complete__c` the user puts 8 hours, then in `Target_Date_Time__c` the value should be 12:00 Pm of next days not the 10:00 pm of the same day in my case its shows 10:00Pm of same days in `Target_Date_Time__c` custom field.

Here is my trigger

```
trigger DailyWorkTrackersTrigger on Invoice__c (before insert, before update) {
     for(Invoice__c workObj: Trigger.new) {
         workObj.Target_Date_Time__c = workObj.Work_Start_Time__c.addMinutes(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(workObj.Estimate_Time_To_Complete_Hrs__c * 1000 * 60 * 60)));
     }
 }
```

Comment: If your day goes 9 to 7 then it's 10 hours, not 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have outlined a textbook use case for `BusinessHours`. Set your default hours up to be 9 to 7. Then, you can just use the `BusinessHours.add` method.

You should also look up trigger best practices and move your logic to an `Apex Class`. Your code could look something like:

```
public with sharing class InvoiceService
{
    static BusinessHours defaultHours
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultHours == null)
            {
                defaultHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            }
            return defaultHours;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public static void setTargetDateTime(List<Invoice__c> invoices)
    {
        for (Invoice__c invoice : invoices) setTargetDateTime(invoice);
    }
    static void setTargetDateTime(Invoice__c invoice)
    {
        Datetime start = invoice.Work_Start_Time__c;
        Long intervalHours = invoice.Estimate_Time_To_Complete_Hrs__c;
        if (start != null && intervalHours != null)
        {
            Long intervalMs = intervalHours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            invoice.Target_Date_Time__c = BusinessHours.add(
                defaultHours.Id, start, intervalMs
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian thanks for your suggestion Its perfect and workin for me